# Charging a Li-Ion/Li-Po Battery with a Power Supply

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, switch-mode-power-supply

I understand that while charging Lithium Ion or Lithium Polymer batteries with a Bench Power Supply, you want to set the max voltage to the appropriate level (i.e. 4.2V for 1S, 8.4V for 2S, etc), and you want to set the charge current to the appropriate level. What I don't understand is do these batteries naturally trickle charge once the power supply switches from CC to CV mode?

Comment: Typically, if you series charge these cells you need a balancer aswell.

Comment: @Unimportant I know, but I was just saying for the sake of clarification. My goal is to charge a single Lithium Ion cell.

Comment: Trickle charge isn't the right word but they continue charging and the current falls from the CC value. At some point (if you're cautious, when it falls to half the CC value, or maybe 1/4) cut the charge altogether because you don't want to trickle charge them. And that means a PSU alone is not good enough.